# Using OLEDB / Microsoft Jet driver causes "Number stored as text" in excel file

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I'm having a problem using OLDEDB from C# to write entries into an excel file. Essentially I want to use an excel template file for formatting some information. The idea is that users can run a query, it'll populate the results into an excel file, where the user can then continue to use excel to maniulate the results.

To do this, I create a "raw_data" tab and use OLEDB to write to it like a table. However I'm running into a problem where the preset calculations. Some columns are text, others are numbers and forumals should reference these columns as soon as the sheet is opened.

Excel Version 2003
C#/.Net 3.5

Here's my connection string

```
string connectString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={filename};Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=0""";
```

{filename} get's replaced later in the code with the path to the file

```
DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.OleDb");
using (DbConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection())
{
  connection.ConnectionString = connectString;
  using (DbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
  {

    connection.Open();
    query = "INSERT INTO [raw_prod$] (correlationid, created, ipaddr, nai, started, delta, csid, bytesin, bytesout, cause, bsid, servopt, svzone) VALUES (\"{correlationid}\", \"{created}\", \"{ipaddr}\", \"{nai}\", \"{started}\", {delta}, \"{csid}\", {bytesin}, {bytesout}, {cause}, \"{bsid}\", \"{servopt}\", \"{zone}\")";
    //Replace {} code with actual values skipped
    command.CommandText = query;
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
}
```

When this run's the data get's populated as expected, but excel treats the data as text, so stuff like sum(c2:c100) don't work. If I simply highlight an entry and hit enter, it will automatically become text. I tried formatting the column to number in the template, and as you can see I remove the double quotes in the sql.

How can I get excel to treat these entries as numeric right off, so that all the calculations will work?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried modifying the reg setting for TypeGuessRows? HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines\Excel\TypeGuessRows should be where to look for Jet 4.0.
For debugging purposes you could set it to a number larger than the default of 8, (or ,if absolutely certain the first row is correct , set it to 1.)

Some links to aid in debugging [Daily Does](http://www.dicks-blog.com/archives/2004/06/03/) and [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/9ec840d0-d132-4837-8cee-d4b89334401c)

Aha! Just spotted the example at the bottom of your code. Try removing the quotes around those values which are numeric

```
\"{correlationid}\", \"{created}\", \"{ipa
```

I am guessing would be

```
{correlationid}, \"{created}\", \"{ipa
```

Comment: I already have it in their without quotes, it's just off screen: {bytesin},

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out, it was actually kind of stupidly annoying. In my excel file for rows 2 - 8 for any column I wanted to be a number I just filled in some dummy numbers. This way the Jet driver when it scans those columns will see the numbers and consider those columns numbers. My inserts from C# are then started on row 9, and I edited the template accordingly to only start calculations from row 9 onward. Really a pain, but it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

You do it by explicitly telling Jet what type the columns are when you create the table for export:

```
 "create table [tabName] ([col1] varchar(255), [col2] double)"
```

The only catch is that if you then try to stick character data into a numeric column Jet will throw when you insert, which is no surprise.

A related issue is how you handle nulls: an empty string is not null as far as Jet's concerned: if you try to insert it into a numeric column, Jet throws up.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Excel 2007 and solved it by doing two things:

- Using the CREATE TABLE method mentioned by philw above
- Modifying the connection string and adding "xml" after the excel 12.0 part

See the following code sample

```
string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=""" + scratchFile 
    + @""";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 xml;HDR=YES""";   

DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.OleDb");

using (DbConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection())
{
    connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;

    using (DbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        connection.Open();

        command.CommandText = @"CREATE TABLE [RawData$] " + 
            "([Organization] varchar(255), " +
            "[Department] varchar(255), [TotalSales] int, [TotalHours] int)";
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        command.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO [RawData$] " +
            "(Organization,Department,TotalSales,TotalHours)" +
            "VALUES('Organization','Department',700,70)";

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }
}
```